# Java Exception: New BMP version not implemented yet

Tags: java, exception, bmp

I converted image with help of GIMP to RGB565.
Now I want to read this bmp-image in java:

```
BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(imagePathFile);
```

but it throws exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: New BMP version not implemented yet
```

What should I do to read this image?

Comment: You should save it as "RGB888" in Gimp to be able to open it. But that is not really the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/) or [Apache Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/sanselan/).

Note that JAI requires some native libraries to be plugged into the JVM whereas Sanselan won't read JPEG images and thus requires you to fall back to ImageIO or even `JPEGImageDecoder` for those.